# Is every countably generated sigma algebra which separates points standard Borel?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

It is very well known that every standard Borel measurable space has a countably generated sigma-algebra which separates points.

Is the converse true? I cannot find a proof or a counterexample anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Counter-example: $(A,\mathcal B(A))$ for any non-borelian set $A\subset\mathbb R$.